# Does postgresql $SYNTAX_CHECK$ validate anything else in the query? existing PKs, missing fields, etc?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax

I'm runnning a `DO $SYNTAX_CHECK$ BEGIN RETURN; query END; $SYNTAX_CHECK$;` and I'm wondering if it's gonna return anything else other than a syntax error. Since it runs the query even though it doesn't make any changes, would it be apparent if there was an issue with a primary key or something like that? a field that does not exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PL/pgSQL checks just syntax. And deeper check (valid identifiers) is only when query is executed.

But maybe you can to look on [plpgsql_check](https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check).